# Only getting Cancel for "Run on server" option.

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, centos

I am using a Tomcat server in Eclipse.
I have added a runtime environment.
But when I choose "run on server", I only get a "Cancel" button.
How can I run my application on the server?
I am using CentOS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question. If you disagree with my edit, you can roll it back, by using the "edit" link below your post.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application a static- or dynamic web project? Check this by right clicking your project name, selecting "Properties". Than search for "Project Facades" and enable "Dynamic Web Project".